# Have all filter checkboxes checked to start when using crosstalk package with reactable in r

Tags: r, checkbox, filter, reactable, crosstalk

Since the default is to not have any filters applied, how can I make all checkboxes filled with a checkmark to start? Using crosstalk package with reactable.

Comment: Please re-phrase your question. Your problem is unclear. Please add some information on what you've tried to fix your problem and where you ran stuck